# ASP.NET Core Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, code-injection

In my asp.net core solution I have 2 projects: asp.net app and library with model layer which contains pattern repository.

I ask DI in app realize my interface

```
services.AddTransient<IRepositrory, Repository>();
```

But! Repository constructor has parameter

```
public Repository(string connectionString)
{
    _appDBContext = new AppDBContext(connectionString);
}
```

How correctly configure DI to create repository with specific string from `appsettings.json` (asp.net app)?

Comment: Your repository class should get `AppDbContext` injected as a dependency. What you have now is not proper DI design

Comment: public Repository(IDBContext dbContext) something like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an overload that accepts an implementation factory

```
services.AddTransient<IRepository>(isp => new Repository(conn));
```

You can get the connection string using

```
Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `AddInstance` method:

```
var connectionString=Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
services.AddInstance<IRepository>(new Repository(connectionString));
```

But I'm agree with @MikeSW what he said in his comment above. You should register your `DbContext` and use it as parameter in your repository constructor:

```
 services.AddDbContext<AppDBContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

And your constructor would be:

```
public Repository(AppDBContext context)
{
    _appDBContext = context;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be putting the services in ConfigureServices method of Startup.cs

```
    public Startup()
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddEntityFramework()
                .AddSqlServer()
                .AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(
            options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["database:connection"]));
     }
```

Where appsettings.json:

```
{
"database": {
"connection":  "Data Source=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=MyDb"
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
services.AddTransient<IRepository>(isp => new Repository(connection));
```

Use this for accepts an implementation factory and to retrieve connection string use this:-

```
Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
```